# Table doesn't display borders

Tags: html, css, xhtml

The following code should display table with borders around cells, but it doesn’t. Any idea why?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv=“content-type” content=“text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1” />
   <style type=“text/css”>
    td, th {border: 1px solid black;}
   </style>
<title>Testing Tony’s Travels</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
     <th>City</th>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Temperature</th>
     <th>Altitude</th>
     <th>Population</th>
     <th>Diner Rating</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Walla Walla, WA</td>
     <td>June 15th</td>
     <td>75</td>
     <td>1,204 ft</td>
     <td>29,686</td>
     <td>4/5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Magic City, ID</td>
     <td>June 25th</td>
     <td>74</td>
     <td>5,312 ft</td>
     <td>50</td>
     <td>3/5</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me if you use the html tag around your text and replace your quotes with actual " or ' (you are using ” which isn't the same. Look closely ” != ")

Comment: As a note, doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).

Comment: Removed the reference to doctype.com. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're missing an opening `<html>` tag; is that just an accident from copy/pasting your code here? Also, fix the quotes in the `meta` and `style` tags:

> `<meta http-equiv="content-type"
>   content="text/html;
>   charset=ISO-8859-1" />` 
>   and 
>   `<style
>   type="text/css">`

Adding a proper [`DOCTYPE`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp) is probably a good idea too, although you'll get borders to display from just making the above fixes.

For future reference, running your HTML through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) or [HTML Tidy](http://infohound.net/tidy/) can instantly identify issues like this.

Comment: I've ommited DOCTYPE and messed up  opening HTML tag when pasting code here. Code is from copied from http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/code/HFHTML_ch13.zip

Answer (score 2):

It shows borders for me in IE6, IE7, IE8, FF3, and Chrome 3, but the borders are around each cell individually.

If you want the borders to appear connected, just add this in your style tag:

`table { border-collapse: collapse; }`

Comment: I've meant to say that there are no borders around individual cells

Answer (score 1):

Is this the whole document?

If it is, you might want to add a document type and html tags.

Comment: I've ommited DOCTYPE and messed up  opening HTML tag when pasting code here. Code is from copied from http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/code/HFHTML_ch13.zip

Answer (score 1):

your double quotes aren't proper double quotes. try

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
    td, th {border: 1px solid black;}
   </style>
<title>Testing Tony’s Travels</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
     <th>City</th>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Temperature</th>
     <th>Altitude</th>
     <th>Population</th>
     <th>Diner Rating</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Walla Walla, WA</td>
     <td>June 15th</td>
     <td>75</td>
     <td>1,204 ft</td>
     <td>29,686</td>
     <td>4/5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Magic City, ID</td>
     <td>June 25th</td>
     <td>74</td>
     <td>5,312 ft</td>
     <td>50</td>
     <td>3/5</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've only tested it on IE6 (sorry - I'm not on my machine) but I think your text editor has inserted 'smart quotes' around the double-quotes strings instead of the straight ones. It seems like just a stylistic change but it is a different character (&ldquo;\&rdquo; instead of &quot;). When I replaced them it rendered the borders.